# Improving a working regex to match multiple lines

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match users from an old DOS dump so they can be migrated to something new. They begin with a `%` sign and end with a `]`. Some on one line and others across many lines.

https://regex101.com/r/0h5ndW/1

My Regex `%([^\%]*)]` works, but is there a better way to select each user beginning from  `%` to the `]` (including the `%` and `]`) so I can put them through `preg_replace` and manipulate them later?

I'm a little skeptical about the multi line part.

`Expected Output`

```
%user:100 [     type=admin,     added=10/12/1997,     last-login:10/20/1997,     total-logins:45,     status:1 ]
%user:111 [     type=user,     added=10/12/1997,     last-login:10/27/1997,     total-logins:145,     status:1 ]
%user:112 [ type=viewer, added=10/12/1997,     last-login:10/23/1997,     total-logins:6,     status:1 ]
%user:113 [ type=viewer, added=10/12/1997,  last-login:10/14/1997,  total-logins:2, status:1]
%user:114 [ type=viewer, added=10/12/1997,  last-login:10/14/1997,  total-logins:1, status:1]
%user:115 [ type=viewer, added=10/12/1997,  last-login:10/12/1997,  total-logins:1, status:1 ]
```

**Raw Data**

```
%user:100 [
    type=admin,
    added=10/12/1997,
    last-login:10/20/1997,
    total-logins:45,
    status:1
]

%user:111 [
    type=user,
    added=10/12/1997,
    last-login:10/27/1997,
    total-logins:145,
    status:1
]

%user:112 [ type=viewer, added=10/12/1997,
    last-login:10/23/1997,
    total-logins:6,
    status:1
]

%user:113 [ type=viewer, added=10/12/1997,  last-login:10/14/1997,  total-logins:2, status:1]

%user:114 [ type=viewer, added=10/12/1997,  last-login:10/14/1997,  total-logins:1, 
status:1]

%user:115 [ type=viewer, added=10/12/1997,  last-login:10/12/1997,  total-logins:1, 
status:1
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex for search:

```
((?:^%|(?!\A)\G).*)\R(?=[^][]*])
```

and replace it with:

```
$1
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0h5ndW/2)

**PHP Code:**

```
$repl = preg_replace('/((?:^%|(?!\A)\G).*)\R(?=[^][]*])/m', '$1', $str);
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `(?:^%|(?!\A)\G)`: Match `%` at line start or restart matching from end of previous match. `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.
  - `.*`: Match everything in same line
- `)`: End capture group #1
- `\R`: Match any kind of newline character
- `(?=[^][]*])`: Make sure we have a `]` ahead without matching `[` or `]` in between.

Comment: Two small observations... the `]` does not seem to be matched in the `RegEx` Demo, and `%user:113` isn't matched at all... Is this normal?

Comment: Both are desired behaviors. 1. `]` is not supposed to be matched because we are removing newline before `]`. 2. `%user:113` isn't matched because it is already in a single line.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a variant of the pattern that you tried with a negated character class to match `%` and from an opening `[` till closing `]`.

Then per match remove the newlines.

```
^%[^][]*\[[^][]*]$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `%[^][]*` Match `%` and 0+ times any char other than `[` or `]`
- `\[[^][]*]` Match from `[` till the closing `]`
- `$` Assert end of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y8gugL/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/IpQ9c)

**For example**

```
$result = preg_replace_callback("/^%[^][]*\[[^][]*]$/m", function($m) {
    return str_replace(PHP_EOL, "", $m[0]);
}, $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to regex, this just splits the data using the `]`.  Then trims each line and replaces new lines (using `PHP_EOL`) with a space...

```
$output = explode("]", $data);
array_pop($output);
array_walk($output, function(&$data) {
    $data = str_replace(PHP_EOL, " ", trim($data)."]");
});
```